# animation to increase height of div while it stays in place

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to build a custom control. I am trying to do something similar to 
[this dropdown](https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index4.html). I am having trouble enlarging the div the way the example does when it is clicked, **increasing the bottom and top while the div stays in place**. I will most probably use my custom control inside a column in bootstrap.

```js
$().ready(function(){
   
  
 
});
```

```css
.customddl {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  margin:0;
  transition: height 1s, margin 1s;
}



.customddl:hover {
 
  height:150px;
  margin:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>


<div class="row mt-5">

<div class="col-3">
<select>
   <option class="form-control">orange</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
   <div class="customddl"> any option v </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: it seems that the example you linked is slidding the content instead of making it grow so you taked the wrong way to copy this behaviour...

Comment: Moreover, you have the codrops article https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/10/inspiration-for-custom-select-elements/

Comment: I've tried several things but I couldn't even get close. So I provided this "poor" snippet.

Comment: you are making a grow transition instead of slide one... Download the source on the codrops article, read it after reading the article, interpret it and then, you can clean the code letting only the piece that you want. Finally edit it as you like.

Comment: pay speciat attention on index4.html

Answer (score -1):

**edit:** just add `transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);` to your class and you will get the desired result.

use `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` and also add `position:relative` to its parent

```js
$().ready(function(){
   
  
 
});
```

```css
.customddl {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  margin:0;
  transition: height 1s, margin 1s;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}



.customddl:hover {
 
  height:150px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>


<div class="row mt-5">

<div class="col-3">
<select>
   <option class="form-control">orange</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
   <div class="customddl"> any option v </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: this only will make the div grow in another direction. He wants a slide effect but is trying to reach it with a growth effect.

Comment: @JoelBonetR I have change code now it is expanding from middle.

Comment: it keeps on the grow effect, can you please, read the question properly and open the codrops example? you'll se a onClick event that slides this navigation menu. Theres no grow effect here. No height transition.

Comment: @JoelBonetR I don't get your point. I am reading the OP, and it seems to me that the question is about increasing the height ...  call it grow or not  ...